# howto find out if a vector contains only one 1 and other are 0? or how to check if every entry is the same?

Tags: matlab

howto find out if a vector contains only one 1 and other are 0? or how to check if every entry is the same?

e.g. i need to check if a vector contains zeros except only one 1 like:

```
(0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0) -> true
(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1) -> true
(0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0) -> false
(0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0) -> false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use logical indexing, assuming your vector is `v`: `numel(v(v==1))` returns the number of elements equal to 1 in your vector.

In the same way, if you want to check if every value is the same you can use: `numel(unique(v))` which returns the number of unique entries of `v`.

Comment: Most precisely, it should be (numel(v(v==1))==1) to get the T/F.

Comment: Using numel(unique(v)) to check if each entry is the same may be a little slow since unique does a sort. I think ~any(v~=v(1)) should be much faster, especially if v has many elements.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different solution:

```
v = [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0];
TF = sum(v==1)==1           %# returns TRUE
```

This is especially useful if you want to apply it to all rows of a matrix:

```
M = [
    0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ;
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ;
    0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 ;
    0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
];
TF = sum(M==1,2)==1
```

The result:

```
>> TF
TF =
     1
     1
     0
     0
```

Comment: How about `2 2 2 1 2 2 2` or `0 0 0 1 0 2`? They will be true, right? I think the solution should also check for unique values. Although it might be out of question's scope.

Comment: you are correct, we should also check that we are dealing only with zeros and ones (in addition to the previous test): `all(v==0|v==1)` or `all(M==0|M==1,2)` in the matrix case

Answer (score 0):

The check for only zeroes could be achieved by extracting all unique elements from your variable:

```
u = unique (v)
```

You can then compare the result to zero and voila.

Answer (score 0):

To check for a non-zero element, use the `find` function. If it finds only one index and that entry is one, your desired result is true. Otherwise it's false.

```
function bool = oneone(vector)
    num = find(vector);
    bool = isscalar(num) && vector(num)==1;
end
```

---

For all same entries, the `diff` function calculates the difference of subsequent elements. If `any` of the results are non-zero, your desired result is false.

```
function bool = allsame(vector)
    d = diff(vector);
    bool = ~any(d);
end
```